# How to count number of small dots in a picture

Tags: image-processing, counting

I have this picture of small particles in a polymer film. I want to count how many particles in the figure, so that I can have a rough estimation of the particle density. But the image quality is poor, I had a hard time to do it.

[image: particle in film - grayscale], [image: particle in film - color]

I have tried several ways to do it, but failed. below is the code.
The first method I tried is:

```
`SetDirectory["C:\\Users\\mayao\\documents"]
image = Import["Picture3.jpg"];
imag2 = Binarize[image, {0.0, 0.8}];
cells = SelectComponents[DeleteBorderComponents[imag2], "Count", -400];

circles = ComponentMeasurements[ImageMultiply[image,cells],"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius"}][[All, 2]]; Show[image, Graphics[{Red, Thick, Circle @@ # & /@ circles}]]
```

Here is what I got:
[image]

So it does not count all the particle. Plus, it sometimes take several particle as one.

I read another method from a thread here, the code is:

```
obl[transit_Image] := (SelectComponents[
     MorphologicalComponents[
      DeleteSmallComponents@
       ChanVeseBinarize[#, "TargetColor" -> Black], 
      Method -> "ConvexHull"], {"Count", "SemiAxes"}, 
     Abs[Times @@ #2 Pi - #1] < #1/100 &]) &@
  transit; GraphicsGrid[{#, obl@# // Colorize, 
    ImageMultiply[#, 
     Image@Unitize@
       obl@#]} & /@ (Import /@ ("C:\\Users\\mayao\\documents\\" <> # \
& /@ {"Picture1.jpg", "Picture2.jpg", "Picture3.jpg", 
       "Picture1.jpg"}))]
```

But it does not recognize the single particles:

[image]

Is there any other method to do this task?
Thanks a lot for any suggestions.

Comment: Check out this blog post by the head of WRI's image processing team: http://blog.wolfram.com/2012/01/04/how-to-count-cells-annihilate-sailboats-and-warp-the-mona-lisa/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

get the binarize image

```
 img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OJd7.jpg"];
 binimg = LocalAdaptiveBinarize[img, 25];
```

[image]

The effect like this:

```
    big = ImageDemosaic[binimg // ColorConvert[#, "Grayscale"] &, 
         "RGGB"] // MinDetect // SelectComponents[#, "Count", # > 100 &] &;
    (array = WatershedComponents[GradientFilter[big, 2], 
        DistanceTransform[big] // MaxDetect]) // Colorize
```

[image]

Then your number is

```
array // Max
```

> 1650

Update===========================================================

Use the `Closing` to optimize the binarize image.

```
binimg = Closing[LocalAdaptiveBinarize[img, 25], 3]
```

[image]

Then we get the array and verify the effect.

```
(array = WatershedComponents[GradientFilter[binimg, 2], 
    DistanceTransform[binimg // ColorNegate] // 
     MaxDetect]) // Colorize
```

[image]

Or you can like this:

```
Show[img, 
 Graphics[{Red, 
   Point[(array /. 1164 -> 0 // 
       ComponentMeasurements[#, "Centroid"] &)[[All, 2]]]}]]
```

[image]

So the number of your component is:

```
array // Max
```

> 1340

Comment: Awesome, this is the most accurate result! One question, what does 1164->0 mean? why specifically 1164?

Answer (score 8):

You could try something like this

```
HighlightImage[
  ImageTake[img, {100, 400}, {100, 400}],
  ImageCorners[
    ImageTake[img, {100, 400}, {100, 400}],
    1.0,
    0.0002,
    10
  ]
]
```

[image: Output of ImageCorners combined with ImageTake.]

for visualization and then

```
Length@
  ImageCorners[
    ImageTake[img, {100, 400}, {100, 400}],
    1.0,
    0.0002,
    10
  ]
```

to get an estimate of the numbers of particles. In any case I would start by selecting a subsection of the image where the lighting is as homogenous as possible. As you can see at the above example there's still a number of false positives and false negatives, and you'll also have to guesstimate the actual area your image is covering in order to calculate the density.

Answer (score 8):

In the post referenced in the comment, the key ideas is

> In order to separate the overlapping cells, I extract a set of markers
>   by finding local maximas of the DistanceTransform and use these as
>   markers in WatershedComponents

However exactly following that example verbatim won't work (because there are hyperparameters) and would give something like this:

[image]

Here are the preprocessing steps I would take:

```
s1 = GradientFilter[img, 5] // ImageAdjust;
s2 = Threshold[s1, {"Hard", "Cluster"}];
s3 = FillingTransform[s2];
s4 = DeleteSmallComponents[s3, 30];
```

The bottom line is that it is tough for a human to delineate the blobs, so it is for a computer. However you can play with the "minimum saliency" threshold as follows:

```
marker = MaxDetect[DistanceTransform[s4, Padding -> 0] // ImageAdjust,
    0.1];

Manipulate[
 w = WatershedComponents[GradientFilter[s4, 3], marker, 
   Method -> {"MinimumSaliency", ms}];
 cells = SelectComponents[w, {"Area", "EquivalentDiskRadius"}, 
   10 < #1 < 1000 && #2 > 4 &];
 measures = 
  ComponentMeasurements[{cells, img}, {"Centroid", 
    "EquivalentDiskRadius", "Area"}];
 Show[img, 
  Graphics[{Thickness[0.003], Opacity[0.6, Yellow], 
    Circle @@ # & /@ (measures[[All, 2, 1 ;; 2]])}], 
  ImageSize -> 800], {ms, 0, 1}]
```

To manually to achieve to desired cell separations:

[image]

which will look much better:

[image]

Comment: Wow!  That looks pretty accurate.  If, for some reason, this approach tends to either overestimate or underestimate the density and a human eye could do a bit better, one might consider a statistical sampling scheme where the whole image is done with your method and then a random sample of smaller rectangles are counted by eye (small enough so that counting would be easy but large enough to contain say at least 10 particles).  The automated estimate would be adjusted by the ratio of the sampled by-eye particles to the sampled counts by the automated method.

Answer (score 4):

The local binarization can help with the uneven lighting. `Dilation` helps disconnect some particles that remain connected, and `DeleteSmallComponents` removes small portions caused by noise.

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OJd7.jpg"];
comps = MorphologicalComponents[DeleteSmallComponents[
        ColorNegate[Dilation[LocalAdaptiveBinarize[img, 10], 1]]]];
comps // Colorize
Max[comps]

984
```

[image]

Comment: The use of `MorphologicalComponents` will lead the result to smaller obviously.

Comment: @yode -- so do the `Dilation` and `DeleteSmallComponents`!