# How can I count the black dots in an image?

Tags: image-processing

[image]

I have put a lot of time trying to count the little black dots with Mathematica image processing tools, but I have not been able to make it get the right count. Please help me.

Comment: Have you looked at the question [How to count number of small dots in a picture](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100957/how-to-count-number-of-small-dots-in-a-picture)?

Comment: yes i saw it but it doesn't work well on the picture because of the border of the petri dish.

Comment: Then please show what you have tried so that people can see what the problem actually is, i.e. that the border of the petri dish makes this problem particularly difficult as opposed to counting black dots on a planar surface.

Comment: It would also help to specify what you believe the correct count to be. Do you want a blob where several have grown over one another to be considered 1 dot or should an estimate be made about how many component dots there are?

Comment: Also [this blog](http://blog.wolfram.com/2012/01/04/how-to-count-cells-annihilate-sailboats-and-warp-the-mona-lisa/) has a cell counting method

Answer (score 3):

One possibility would be to count the black pixels:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XgZ1.jpg"]
bin = ColorNegate@Binarize[img, 0.4];
data = ImageData@bin;
Total@Flatten@data
```

returns about 7800 black pixels. Then you just have to divide by the average "dot" size in pixels (depending on what you call "dot", see kjosborne comment). This way, you have no problem with the Petri dish :)

If you want an idea for what the average pixel size compensation would look like:

```
 blobSizes = Values[ComponentMeasurements[bin, "Count"]];
 dotCount = Total[bin]/Median[blobSizes]
```

*Do `Total@Flatten@data` in place of `Total[bin]` if you don't have 11.2, but if you do, arithmetic like Total works on Image and Image3D objects.

This returns 562. dots. You can of course choose a different way to choose a representative from the `blobSizes` list to suit your needs.

[image]

If you are not interested in dots, but in the proportion of the Petri dish with black dots:

```
bin2 = ColorNegate@Binarize[img, .99]
data2 = ImageData@bin2;
Total@Flatten@data2
(* 191139 *)
7868/% 
(* 0.0411638 *)
```

so that's about 4.1%.

Comment: I would add to this a use of ComponentMeasurements to get PixelCount for each blob. The Median of that is probably a fair estimate for one dot's size.

Comment: @kjosborne I'm not familiar with this, feel free to edit/add your answer/comment or whatever! Or I'll try.